# How do I use my jQuery slidetoggle more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my jQuery slidetoggle and it works for the first `<div>` but when adding more flip's and panel's it won't work. It has to be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bxk069dp/2/).
I click on the one above and it works. The second one doesn't even react. How do I fix that?

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel, #flip {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #e5eecc;
border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
padding: 50px;
display: none;
}

#panel1, #flip1 {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #e5eecc;
border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel1 {
padding: 50px;
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

<br><br>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">This example below won't work. Why not?</h1><br>    <br>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the seconds panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

<br><br>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">To fix this I could try using different names for the flip and panel such as flip1 and panel1</h1><br><br>


<div id="flip1">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique, use classes instead, then in the click handler you have to toggle the next sibling element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID must be unique here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bxk069dp/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#flip1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

please use jsfiddle as below [better version](https://jsfiddle.net/bxk069dp/4/)  :)

Comment: I forgot to say, I know this method obviously.. I mean, I want it to do something like ++ when using a loop.